# How to show a list of users based on taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I want show a list of users by selecting taxonomy.
and also I wanted to add taxonomy field in users profile/registration form and I did this with  [profile_taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/profile_taxonomy) module.

Suppose I have different taxonomy like "Technology","Eduaction","Stocks" then by clicking on any of this I want the list of users who had selected the same taxonomy.
I can get the list by visiting user profile and then by clicking on taxonomy i can get the same list. but i want to make seperate page for it where the list of taxonomy vocabulary is shown.
Please suggest solution.
I am extremely new to Drupal and also I am not a PHP programmer.
I am using Drupal 6

Answer (score 1):

First a little clarification of term meanings.  Taxonomy is a module that manages groups of terms gathered in Vocabularies.  You have probably created a vocabulary with the terms you listed in it.

To make your list you will use Views.  I am using D7 and V3, so I cannot give you a button by button instructions, but they are similar.

1. Add a new view.
2. Define the settings for fields and add a field for the User:name.  To do this in D7 you must add a relationship to the content author to expose the User Name field.  I don't think this is needed in D6.
3. Delete the node title field.
4. Set the path to a unique URL such as `Group-Type/%/users`.
5. Create an argument to filter the URL input '%' by a taxonomy term ID based upon the vocabulary you are using for the selection terms.

When you enter a URL such as Group-type/stocks/users, The view should be used to generate a list of Users with that term.

A cautionary thought:  I have not used D6 version of Views so I don't know its idiosyncrasies.  You may have to use the term id (tid) for 'stocks' since Drupal has changed a URL from an alias to a tid by the time the URL is passed to the argument section of the module.